# Rails - Optimistic locking always fires StaleObjectError exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, optimistic-locking

I'm learning rails, And read about optimistic lock. I've added `lock_version` column of type `integer` into my `articles` table.

But now whenever I try to update a record **for the first time**, I get `StaleObjectError` exception.

Here's my migration:

```
class AddLockVersionToArticle < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :articles, :lock_version, :integer
  end
end
```

When I try updating an article through rails console:

```
article = Article.first
=> #<Article id: 1, title: "Ccccc", text: "dfdsfsdfsdf", created_at: "2015-02-20 21:58:45", updated_at: "2015-02-25 20:03:12", lock_version: 0>
```

And I do:

```
article.title = "new title"
article.save
```

I get this:

```
(0.3ms)  begin transaction
   (0.3ms)  UPDATE "articles" SET "title" = 'dwdwd', "updated_at" = '2015-02-25 20:40:36.537876', "lock_version" = 1 WHERE ("articles"."id" = 1 AND "articles"."lock_version" = 0)
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError: Attempted to update a stale object: Article
```

Comment: Maybe it's the default, but the lock version column should have a default value of 0 (in the database)

Comment: are u sure u doing it for first time?

Comment: @FrederickCheung lock_version is already 0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to initialize all the articles lock_version to 0.
Look at the query:

```
UPDATE "articles" SET "title" = 'dwdwd', "updated_at" = '2015-02-25 20:40:36.537876', "lock_version" = 1 WHERE ("articles"."id" = 1 AND "articles"."lock_version" = 0)
       (0.1ms)
```

If the query returns 0 records updated, then the framework suppose that you have updated the version or deleted the object in another thread.

Comment: So the migrations should have been: `add_column :articles, :lock_version, :integer, default: 0, null: false`

Comment: i vote down, lock_version is already 0, and in the example, author using bin/rails console

Comment: @CodeGroover Apparently rails console is showing `lock_verison` to have 0 value. But when I inspected the database it had `null` value. Changing the column to have a default values solved the problem.